Error 5455 when uploading to Cloudflare images using python library
I use the latest version of the python library from Cloudflare to try to upload an image programmatically to my Cloudflare Images account.
The code is quite simple:
import io
from pathlib import Path
from cloudflare import Cloudflare

if __name__ == '__main__':
    secrets = loadSecrets()
    image = Path("E:/").joinpath("test", "test_pict.jpg")
    cf = Cloudflare(api_token = secrets["image"]["apitoken"])
    with open(image, "rb") as imgfile:
     res = cf.images.v1.create(account_id = secrets["accid"], file = imgfile)

Since the documentation is very generic about the "file" parameter:
    def create(self,
               *,
               account_id: str,
               file: object | NotGiven = NOT_GIVEN,
               metadata: object | NotGiven = NOT_GIVEN,
               require_signed_urls: bool | NotGiven = NOT_GIVEN,
               url: str | NotGiven = NOT_GIVEN,
               extra_headers: Mapping[str, str | Omit] | None = None,
               extra_query: Mapping[str, object] | None = None,
               extra_body: object | None = None,
               timeout: float | Timeout | None | NotGiven = NOT_GIVEN) -> Image
     
    Upload an image with up to 10 Megabytes using a single HTTP POST (multipart/ form-data) request. An image can be uploaded by sending an image file or passing an accessible to an API url.
     
    Args: 
    account_id: Account identifier tag.  
    file: An image binary data. Only needed when type is uploading a file. 
    ...

I tried various options:
res = cf.images.v1.create(account_id = secrets["accid"], file = image)
res = cf.images.v1.create(account_id = secrets["accid"], file = imgfile.read())
res = cf.images.v1.create(account_id = secrets["accid"], file = io.open(image, "rb)

but always throws the same error:

cloudflare.APIStatusError: Error code: 415 - {'result': None,
'success': False, 'errors': [{'code': 5455, 'message': 'Uploaded image
must have image/jpeg, image/png, image/webp, image/gif or
image/svg+xml content-type'}], 'messages': []}

The image is a 2.5MB Jpeg (I checked the header with Hex Editor, just in case).
Any educated guess on what else I should try that may fix that will be most appreciated.

cloudflare-python uses httpx under the hood. After looking at the internals of the code and spending some fun time debugging, I saw that:

file is supposed to be an object with a structure such as:


file ={ "file": imgfile.read() }

probably the formats described in httpx for multipart file uploads also work, but since cloudflare-python is broken (read below), I had no way to check.

cf.images.v1.create() is broken. The data that it sends in the post request to the Cloudflare Images endpoint does not match their API spec. I could not find any way to define files or metadata that got the request accepted by the endpoint, but always got a 400 response.

One of the first things that I did was to look into the test cases, and there is not a single one that covers this upload alternative. But there are for what they call "direct upload URL", which is actually an indirect upload procedure.
Cloudflare does not allow report issues in their github repo so I reported this in their Community and discord channel. In the meanwhile a simple httpx post request to the API endpoint works quite OK:
if __name__ == '__main__':
    secrets = loadSecrets()
    image = Path("E:/").joinpath("test", "test_pict2.jpg")
    url = f'https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/accounts/{secrets["accid"]}/images/v1'
    headers = {
        'Authorization': f'Bearer {secrets["image"]["apitoken"]}'
    }
    data = {
        'metadata': json.dumps({ "id": "12345" })
    }
    files = {
        'file': (image.stem, open(image, 'rb'), 'image/jpeg')}
    r = httpx.post(url, headers=headers, data=data, files=files)

A tip, do not change the name of "metadata" or "file" or the API will respond with 400.
